# Formatting of Excel sheets in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

In my project I am opening an Excel file with multiple sheets. I want to manipulate "sheet2" in Python (which works fine) and after that overwrite the old "sheet2" with the new one but KEEP the formatting.. so something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

update_sheet2 = pd.read_excel(newest_isaac_file, sheet_name='sheet2')
#do stuff with the sheet

 with pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace', mode='a', 
                                                               KEEP_FORMATTING = True) as writer:
           df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index=index)
```

In other words: Is there a way to get the formatting from an existing Excel sheet?
I could not find anything about that. I know I can manually set the formatting in Python but the formatting of the existing sheet is really complicated and has to stay the same.

thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this need to be done using ExcelWriter or are you ok using `openpyxl`? Text only changes without changing the formatting is possible with the latter. Let me know if that is ok

Comment: I think `openpyxl` would work too. If possible I would like to do the changes of the sheet with pandas (I am flexible on that too). If it helps here is what I want to do:
Take old sheet -> insert new line (somewhere in the middle) -> copy contents of another line to the new one (keep/copy formatting)-> change some values of new line  ("values" are: percentage values and some strings /datetimes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, try this code. It will open a file (Sample.xlsx), go to a sheet (Sheet1), insert new row at 15, copy the text and formatting from row 22 and paste it in the empty row (row 15). Code and final screen shot attached.

```
import openpyxl
from copy import copy
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx') #Load workbook
ws=wb['Sheet1'] #Open sheet
ws.insert_rows(15, 1) #Insert one row at 15 and move everything one row downwards

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=22, max_row=22, min_col=1, max_col=ws.max_column): # Read values from row 22
    for cell in row:
        ws.cell(row=15, column=cell.column).value = cell.value #Update value to row 22 to new row 15
        ws.cell(row=15, column=cell.column)._style = copy(cell._style) #Copy formatting
wb.save('Sample.xlsx')
```

**How excel looks after running the code**

[image]

Comment: wow so there is a copy formatting option.. I could not find it. 
Thanks a lot!